# Let $A$ be a non-singular matrix such that $3ABA^{-1}+A=2A^{-1}BA$ then determine whether $A+B$ and $ABA^{-1}-A^{-1}BA$ are singular or non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be a non-singular matrix such that $$3ABA^{-1}+A=2A^{-1}BA$$ then determine whether $A+B$ and $ABA^{-1}-A^{-1}BA$ are singular or non-singular.

My Attempt:

If I put $A=I$ then both $A+B$ and $ABA^{-1}-A^{-1}BA$ are singular. But I am not able to generate a proper way to prove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
A+B&= A(I+A^{-1}B)=(I+BA^{-1})A\\
(A+B)(2A)&=A(I+A^{-1}B)(2A)\\
(A+B)(2A)&=A(2A+2A^{-1}BA)\\
&=A(2A+3ABA^{-1}+A)\\
&=A^2(3I+3BA^{-1})\\
&= 3A^2(I+BA^{-1})\\
2(I+BA^{-1})A^{2}&=3A^{2}(I+BA^{-1})\\
2^n\det(I+BA^{-1})&=3^n\det(I+BA^{-1})
\end{align}

Hence $I+BA^{-1}$ is not invertible which implies that $A+B$ is not invertible.

---

\begin{align}
ABA^{-1}-A^{-1}BA &= \frac13 \left(3ABA^{-1}-3A^{-1}BA \right)\\
&=\frac13(-A-A^{-1}BA)\\
&= -\frac13(I+A^{-1}B)A
\end{align}

Since $I+A^{-1}B$ is singular, $ABA^{-1}-A^{-1}BA$ is singular as well.

Comment: What happens for a characteristic $3$?

Comment: Where do you need the assumption that the matrices are real?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to evaluate it for a particular case of $A$, try solving the equation for $A+B$ and $ABA^{-1}-A^{-1}BA$.